# Linking issue between python script, flask framework, and html

Tags: python, html, highcharts, flask, init

I am having an odd issue with transferring the correct data from my python script to a graph (highcharts) in my html.  I am using Flask web framework and a Ubuntu server.  I have two identical html webpages in structure but they differ in the data passed to them (data originates from two separate dbs).  Each webpage have multiple graphs (highcharts), one particular graph on the second webpage is returns incorrect data points.  It returns the data points intended for the first webpage. This issue does not show up when I test on my local host, only when running on the server (yes I have correctly copied the files to my server).  As you might not be able to pinpoint the issue, any ideas in terms of troubleshooting or reasons why my Ubuntu server wouldn't refresh properly is very much welcome.  I apologize if this question is unclear, it isn't the easiest problem to convey through text.  Here is example code...I run scripts in python over my server and they are relayed to my html through my flask init file.

**PYTHON SCRIPT**

```
import os, sqlite3, datetime, pandas as pd, numpy as np

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
DATABASE = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'folder', 'my.db') 
conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE) 
c = conn.cursor()

averages_lm = (pd.read_sql("SELECT AVG(points_for) AS points_for, AVG(points_against) AS points_against, \
                          AVG(num_moves) AS moves, AVG(num_trades) AS trades, AVG(wins) AS wins, AVG(losses) AS losses, \
                          manager_name FROM standings WHERE curweek > 14 GROUP BY manager_name", conn))

averages_ex = (pd.read_sql("SELECT AVG(points_for) AS points_for, AVG(points_against) AS points_against, \
                          AVG(num_moves) AS moves, AVG(num_trades) AS trades, AVG(wins) AS wins, AVG(losses) AS losses, \
                          manager_name FROM standings_ex WHERE curweek > 14 GROUP BY manager_name", conn))


def averages_LM():
    global averages_lm
    return averages_lm

def averages_EX():
    global averages_ex
    return averages_ex
```

**INIT FILE**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request, jsonify, json
import requests
import os, sys

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'Yahoo_Fantasy'))

from stats_fantasy import *

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/html1')
def LowerMerion():

    averages = averages_lm()
    len_averages = len(averages['managers'])
    return render_template("html-1.html", title="title", averages=averages, len_averages=len_averages)

@app.route('/html2')
def SimgaChi():

    averages = averages_ex()
    len_averages = len(averages['managers'])
    return render_template("html-2.html", title="title", averages=averages, len_averages=len_averages)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(debug=True)
```

**HTML** (snippet)

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#chart-4').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Career Averages Per Season '
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Regular Season'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [ {% for i in range(len_managers) %} '{{ averages.manager_name[i] }}', {% endfor %}

            ],
            crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total Per Season'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} pts</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Avg Wins',
            data: [{% for i in range(len_managers) %} {{ averages.wins[i] }}, {% endfor %}]

        }, {
            name: 'Avg Losses',
            data: [{% for i in range(len_managers) %} {{ averages.losses[i] }}, {% endfor %}]

        }, {
            name: 'Avg Moves',
            data: [{% for i in range(len_managers) %} {{ averages.moves[i] }}, {% endfor %}]

        }, {
            name: 'Avg Trades',
            data: [{% for i in range(len_managers) %} {{ averages.trades[i] }}, {% endfor %}]

        }, {
            name: 'Avg Draft Pick',
            data: [{% for i in range(len_managers) %} {{ draft_pos.pick[i] }}, {% endfor %}]

        }, ]
    });
});
</script>
```

Again, Something odd is going on...as the script will change when I modify text for the graphs, but for whatever reason the data being passed to it is the data from function averages_LM().  I think I incorrectly passed it this data from the beginning and now it doesn't seem to want to change.

Comment: I reduced the code to try to include only the important factors due to it's length.  Please let me know if there is any pertinent information I did not present or properly present the first time.  Thanks

Comment: Could you show what is **generated** on the client side(html) in this places: `{% for i in range(len_managers) %} {{ draft_pos.pick[i] }}, {% endfor %}` ?

Comment: Since it worked on my local host I basically deleted everything from my server and replaced with my desktop environment and all works now.

Answer (score 0):

After a first look at your code, it seems that you are returning the same datas in the two views. The line:

```
averages = averages_LM()
```

is the same on the both view, shouldn't one of them be

```
averages = averages_EX()
```

?

Also, if your two html templates are identical, you don't need to create two separate pages, you can simply have one template for both views, the content of the template will depends on the data you pass from the view.

Comment: I apologize, that was an error in my post.  I corrected to have the init file return the correct functions.  I can try returning a single html template and see how that may help.  However, I have similar functions and scripts that run fine within the same python scripts and html, so I am not sure that will fix things.    It is more so the fetching or pushing of the data, certain things seem to update instantly while other modifications to python/init have no effect.

Comment: No problems. Having only one template should not help for your problem but it just make the code more easy to maintain.  Is your javascript inside your html file or on a separate file?